# noun phrase types

Tags: nouns

***What are (1) [NP e], (2) control PRO; pro, other instances, and (3) 'e' in the examples? ('NP' here is actually a subscript in the paper)***

---

I'm reading Barbara Abott's '[Definiteness and Indefiniteness](https://www.msu.edu/~abbottb/def_and_indef.pdf).' In its 'Introduction,' she enumerates definite noun phrases. In the list I see something like this:

```
NP type: [NP e]
More details: control PRO; pro; other instances of ellipsis
Examples: Mary tried e to fly; [on a pill packet] e contains methanol [=Ariel 1988, ex. 7a]
```

What are (1) [NP e], (2) control PRO; pro, other instances, and (3) 'e' in the examples? ('NP' here is actually a subscript in the paper)

Answer (score 1):

*e* in this parlance refers to any *empty category*, i.e. a phonologically null element in the structure. They can be of various types indeed, such as

- movement traces, more often denoted as *t*
- controlled PRO, i.e. an empty element that typically occupies subject position in infinitives and receives reference via subject or object *control*:

  (1) Mary<sub>i</sub> tried PRO<sub>i</sub> to fly.
- small *pro* that occupies argument positions in pro-drop languages: cf. Italian

  (2) *pro*<sub>[1pl]</sub> parliamo. `we speak'
- under some theories, an empty pronoun in the ellipsis site, and the *e* can be verbal:

  (3) John didn't win, bit he tried to [<sub>VP</sub> *e*].

As you can see in three, a superscript in the brackets is actually not specific to NPs, it is notation to specify the category of the constituent enclosed in the brackets; thus, [<sub>NP</sub> cake] means that the constituent "cake" is an NP, [<sub>VP</sub> ate cake] means that "ate cake" is a VP etc.